# Permanently save the changes done to an array

Tags: php, arrays, function, variables

i want that the last number that i add to an the array remains in the array permanently.I want to do this because i want to add a number every time i change the value passed to foo function.The function is this:

```
<?php
    $numbers=[1,2,3,4];

    function foo($number){
         global $numbers;
         $lenght=count($numbers);
         $numbers[$lenght]=$number;
     }

     foo(3);
     print_r($numbers);
<?
```

Comment: If you pass the array as a paramter to the function you dont need the global as well

Comment: You will need to store the array values somewhere, like a database or text file.

Comment: I can see what the code should be doing but I can't tally it up with what you're saying you're trying to achieve ... so what *exactly* are you trying to do?

Comment: Please clarify what you want to achieve

Comment: In this particular example, the function foo() can be replaced by `$numbers[] = 3;`

Comment: @NigelRen - the function seems like it should replace the last item in the array *not* append a new one - however I'm not sure what the actual intention is so you could be correct about that being the desired outcome.

Comment: I want to achieve this:I call foo function with a number.That number has to be stored at the end of the array numbers.I change the value passed to foo function and that value has to be stored at the end of the array numbers without deleting the previous number that I have added.

Comment: @CD001 - as count is the number of elements (4 in the example) and arrays are 0 based, this will add the item at position 4 (to the end of the array).

Comment: @NigelRen ... that's why I said *should* ;) I was guessing at the intention rather than what it actually does... otherwise it seems a **really** convoluted way of just doing `$numbers[] = ...` as you said ;)

Comment: @mmecol "*I change the value passed to foo function and that value has to be stored at the end of the array numbers without deleting the previous number that I have added."* ... if the function is being called on page load then you're going to need some kind of persistent storage - the state of the application is not maintained between page loads otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

you can using **array_push**

```
$numbers=[1,2,3,4];
$number = [];
function foo($number)
{
     $lenght=count($numbers);
     array_push( $number, $length);
 }
```